# Help with ASP.Net C# chart control

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, charts

Im creating a web application which is used a reporting application. so far I have managed to create an application which queries a Interbase database and stores the result of the query into a dataset which looks like

```
NAME | GP   | ORD_GP | EXP   | TOTAL GP | TARGET
a      206     48      -239     15         1600
b      0       27       0        27        1520
```

this data is then used to create some column charts. which like these

[image]

what I now need to be able to do is create another chart which will show an hourly line graph of the TOTAL GP, the problem is the web application queries the database every three minutes to get new data and store it in a dataset and then display the new column graph.

can someone please advice how I might be able to create a line graph for the TOTAL GP taking into account that this data is constantly changing.

Comment: mhh... sorry, i don't really understand your problem. where are you stuck? what have you tried so far? what did not work as you expected?

Comment: I haven't actually tried anything so far I wanted advice on how I should go about creating a line graph which is updated every hour. the issue is at the moment the data is pulled from a database every 3 mins and the TOTAL GP is calculated on the fly, because of this the TOTAL GP isnt actually stored anywhere. so how would I go about creating a line graph which will show an hourly update of the TOTAL GP for each person ? hope this makes sense now

Answer (score 0):

i'd use some background daemon/sheduled task/etc on a server to regulary calculate the "snapshot" value of "total gp" and store that somewhere (db table) with a timestamp...

your web application knows the last displayed timestamp of those snapshots and can query everything that's newer whenever desired (e.g. every 3 min)